# Http response status code constants

Tags: dart

I'm building a client side app (in the browser) and I can't find if there exists a list of Http response status codes somewhere.

All the libraries seem to use numbers like `404`, `200`, etc.. but I find it not too readable.

Is there a standardized place where I could use something like `NOT_FOUND` for `404` and other constants for other codes?

I've seen Shelf.response that provides factory methods for this, but it's also only usable on the Dart vm if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only available in `dart:io` but not in `dart:html`.

Comment: GitHub: https://github.com/bwu-dart/http_exception/blob/master/lib/http_status.dart pub: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http_exception)